# Find daily stock updates in mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Here Stock collection stores every transaction (sale, purchase, return, cancel).
StockSummary keeps the summary of every product where 'product_id' is a unique value.
Product collection '_id' refers to 'product_id' of StockSummary.

Now, need to find out a daily basis report including

> "product_import_id","product_name", "Opening
> Stock","daily_purchase","daily_sales","daily_return","Current Stock"

```
CurrentStock = opening_stock+total_purchase+ total_return+ total_cancel - total_sales
```

Product Collection(example):

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef0366dd65edf0a1b9f4a16"),
    "name" : "BCS Preliminary Analysis (Paperback)",
    "import_id" : 322953
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eef063ff4b01673536e8959"),
    "name" : "Secondary Higher Mathematics Special Supplement (English Version)",
    "import_id" : 322952
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eef05d8f4b01673536e8952"),
    "name" : "Secondary Physics Special Supplement (English Version)",
    "import_id" : 322951
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eef053cf4b01673536e894b"),
    "name" : "Secondary Mathematics Special Supplement (English Version)",
    "import_id" : 322950
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eee242711046e51714970d8"),
    "name" : "Secondary Physical Education: Health Science and Sports (English Version)",
    "import_id" : 322949
}
```

StockSummary Collection(example):

```
 /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dadae82ede4e32970f160d8"),
    "opening_stock" : 0,
    "total_purchase" : 5,
    "purchase_rate" : 240,
    "total_sales" : 6,
    "total_cancel" : 0,
    "total_return" : 2,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5a82ded9f198d8fc483ca8c0"),
    "updated_by" : ObjectId("5da430aecf21ca288d9a20d4"),
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ee07c7e2b00654df12679b4"),
            "commented_by" : ObjectId("5e42733acbc7312cfdef56c9"),
            "commented_at" : ISODate("2020-06-10T06:23:58.059Z")
        }
    ],
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2020-06-14T05:08:17.480Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "supplier" : ObjectId("5e315bb1323fe83ff9fcf99e")
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dadae83ede4e32970f160db"),
    "opening_stock" : 2,
    "total_purchase" : 1,
    "purchase_rate" : 210,
    "total_sales" : 2,
    "total_cancel" : 0,
    "total_return" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5a82ded9f198d8fc483ca946"),
    "updated_by" : ObjectId("5a7028d9a0a6013c7d03a376"),
    "comments" : [],
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-12-18T11:10:04.829Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "supplier" : ObjectId("5a9653707d3e2bab2f16a9f7")
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dadae83ede4e32970f160e0"),
    "opening_stock" : 1,
    "total_purchase" : 1,
    "purchase_rate" : 113,
    "total_sales" : 2,
    "total_cancel" : 0,
    "total_return" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5a82dedef198d8fc483cbce6"),
    "updated_by" : ObjectId("5a658361e579ee753600f753"),
    "comments" : [],
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-12-19T11:29:25.707Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "supplier" : ObjectId("5ad4a1044aaa29765ed85697")
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dadae83ede4e32970f160e5"),
    "opening_stock" : 1,
    "total_purchase" : 0,
    "purchase_rate" : 325,
    "total_sales" : 1,
    "total_cancel" : 0,
    "total_return" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5a82dee0f198d8fc483cc4bc"),
    "updated_by" : ObjectId("5a658361e579ee753600f753"),
    "comments" : [],
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-10-21T13:11:31.123Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "supplier" : ObjectId("5a9653707d3e2bab2f16a9f7")
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dadae83ede4e32970f160ea"),
    "opening_stock" : 1,
    "total_purchase" : 0,
    "purchase_rate" : 90,
    "total_sales" : 0,
    "total_cancel" : 0,
    "total_return" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5a82e201beb4177e4c32b6e5"),
    "updated_by" : ObjectId("5a658361e579ee753600f753"),
    "comments" : [],
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2019-10-21T13:11:31.128Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "supplier" : ObjectId("5bcee5cc183e2638727cdce1")
}
```

Stock Collection(example):

```
 /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dae84febb1818461191c28b"),
    "purchase_qty" : 0,
    "purchase_rate" : 0,
    "purchase_cost" : 0,
    "sales_qty" : 1,
    "sales_rate" : 150,
    "sales_price" : 150,
    "cancel_qty" : 0,
    "return_qty" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5d70b94d739e864634fa1c9c"),
    "product_name" : "দিকদর্শন কৃষি সম্প্রসারণ অধিদপ্তর-এর নিয়োগ সহায়িকা (পেপারব্যাক)",
    "sales_order_id" : ObjectId("5daae5a2ffade94f51472bab"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-10-22T04:26:18.079Z"),
    "created_by" : ObjectId("5a7028d9a0a6013c7d03a376"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dae8501bb1818461191c28e"),
    "purchase_qty" : 0,
    "purchase_rate" : 0,
    "purchase_cost" : 0,
    "sales_qty" : 1,
    "sales_rate" : 150,
    "sales_price" : 150,
    "cancel_qty" : 0,
    "return_qty" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5d70b94d739e864634fa1c9c"),
    "product_name" : "দিকদর্শন কৃষি সম্প্রসারণ অধিদপ্তর-এর নিয়োগ সহায়িকা (পেপারব্যাক)",
    "sales_order_id" : ObjectId("5daad86effade94f51472b5e"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-10-22T04:26:21.648Z"),
    "created_by" : ObjectId("5a7028d9a0a6013c7d03a376"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dae8505bb1818461191c291"),
    "purchase_qty" : 0,
    "purchase_rate" : 0,
    "purchase_cost" : 0,
    "sales_qty" : 1,
    "sales_rate" : 483,
    "sales_price" : 483,
    "cancel_qty" : 0,
    "return_qty" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5b5d898638da5146799c1d2f"),
    "product_name" : "বিসিএস প্রিলিমিনারী অ্যানালাইসিস (পেপারব্যাক)",
    "sales_order_id" : ObjectId("5daae8a9ffade94f51472bdc"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-10-22T04:26:25.176Z"),
    "created_by" : ObjectId("5a7028d9a0a6013c7d03a376"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dae8508bb1818461191c294"),
    "purchase_qty" : 0,
    "purchase_rate" : 0,
    "purchase_cost" : 0,
    "sales_qty" : 1,
    "sales_rate" : 350,
    "sales_price" : 350,
    "cancel_qty" : 0,
    "return_qty" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5d6cfee3739e864634fa06ae"),
    "product_name" : "সফলতা বান্ডেল",
    "sales_order_id" : ObjectId("5daad631ffade94f51472b48"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-10-22T04:26:28.855Z"),
    "created_by" : ObjectId("5a7028d9a0a6013c7d03a376"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dae850cbb1818461191c297"),
    "purchase_qty" : 0,
    "purchase_rate" : 0,
    "purchase_cost" : 0,
    "sales_qty" : 1,
    "sales_rate" : 158,
    "sales_price" : 158,
    "cancel_qty" : 0,
    "return_qty" : 0,
    "product_id" : ObjectId("5d5cc489e458243a228478c7"),
    "product_name" : "প্রধানমন্ত্রীর কার্যলয়ের এমসিকিউ",
    "sales_order_id" : ObjectId("5dab29f5ffade94f51472e07"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2019-10-22T04:26:32.407Z"),
    "created_by" : ObjectId("5a7028d9a0a6013c7d03a376"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer Query:

```
db.getCollection("stocks").aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                "year" : {
                    "$year" : "$created_at"
                }, 
                "month" : {
                    "$month" : "$created_at"
                }, 
                "day" : {
                    "$dayOfMonth" : "$created_at"
                }, 
                "product_id" : "$product_id",
                "purchase_qty" : "$purchase_qty",
                "sales_qty" : "$sales_qty",
                "return_qty" : "$return_qty"
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
                "_id" : {
                   "product_id" : "$product_id",
                    "year" : "$year", 
                    "month" : "$month", 
                    "day" : "$day",
                    
                    
                },
                "sales": {$sum:  "$sales_qty"},
                "purchases": {$sum:  "$purchase_qty"},
                "returns": {$sum:  "$return_qty"}
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $lookup: // Equality Match
            {
                from: "products",
                localField: "_id.product_id",
                foreignField: "_id",
                as: "product"
            }
            
        },

        // Stage 4
        {
            $lookup: // Equality Match
            {
                from: "stocksummaries",
                localField: "_id.product_id",
                foreignField: "product_id",
                as: "stock_sum"
            }

        },

        // Stage 5
        {
            $project: {
                "_id" : "$_id.product_id", 
                
                //"year" : "$_id.year", 
                "month" : "$_id.month", 
                "day" : "$_id.day", 
                "product_import_id" :  { $arrayElemAt: [ "$product.import_id", 0 ] },
                "product_name" : { $arrayElemAt: [ "$product.name", 0 ] } ,
                "Opening Stock": {$arrayElemAt: [ "$stock_sum.opening_stock", 0 ]},
                "daily_purchase": "$purchases",
                "daily_sales": "$sales",
                "daily_return": "$returns",
                "Current Stock": { $subtract: [
                    {$sum: [{$arrayElemAt: [ "$stock_sum.opening_stock", 0 ]},{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$stock_sum.total_purchase", 0 ]},{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$stock_sum.total_cancel", 0 ]},{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$stock_sum.total_return", 0 ]}] },
                   {$ifNull: [
                       {$arrayElemAt: [ "$stock_sum.total_sales", 0 ]},
                       0
                        ]}
                    ]}
                
            }
        },

    ]

);
```